# .htaccess rewrite loop error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to be able to make it so that when someone visits my site at say:

a) http://www.mysite.co.uk/

It actually displays the content from:

b) http://www.mysite.co.uk/catalog/index.php

and also if a user types in (b) then they are 301'd to (a)

In my .htaccess I currently have the following but this causes a 301 loop error

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ catalog/index.php [L]
Redirect 301 /catalog/index.php http://www.mysite.co.uk
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the second line ? Remove it. Write first line as `RewriteRule ^/?$ catalog/index.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: This causes a weird redirect on www.mysite.co.uk to the following www.mysite.co.uk/home/sites/catalog/index.php
/home/sites/catalog/ is the server path - very odd

Comment: May be I am confused, but I don't see "home/" in any of your rule. Your 2nd rule seems responsible for the loop error.

Comment: Exactly home is the server path. Here is your code working on an empty test domain. All that is in the .htaccess is your suggestion
http://www.funonthebed.com

Comment: So, "http://www.funonthebed.com/home/funonthe/public_html/" is your web root?

Comment: yes, odd why its doing this. Did the same on the live site on a different server

Comment: A tricky way to get this done. Redirect [here](www.funonthebed.com/home/funonthe/public_html/../../../catalog/index.php) ..Use `RewriteRule ^/?$ ../../../catalog/index.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: that works but redirects / to catalog/index.php basically the opposite to my original question

Comment: Can you give me the source url and and the one where you want it to be redirected to? Actual url's not needed, even some example may work.

Comment: Not sure what you need that isnt in my original question. When someone types in www.funonthebed.com they stay on this url but shown the content of /catalog/index.php. Because catalog/index.php is indexed in Google I need anyone coming directly to /catalog/index.php to be 301d to www.funonthebed.com. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the following lines:

```
#Permanently redirect BROWSER requests for the .php script to the Site root:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /catalog/index.php     [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/   [R=301,L]

#Internal redirect (Alias) the root of the site to: /catalog/index.php
RewriteRule ^$                  /catalog/index.php      [L]
```